# How to unmap memory mapped file from all views?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I have a memory-mapped file on disk in my application. My application creates multiple threads and all of them are memory mapping the same file at the same time or different time. In one of the threads, I am calling `unmapViewOfFile` followed by `SetFilePointer` and `SetEndOfFile`. `SetEndOfFile` call fails with error `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE`. [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/125713/common-file-mapping-problems-and-platform-differences) links suggests this is a known problem that it requires to unmap all views of a mapped file. How to check if a file is still mapped in another thread/process and how to unmap it from all the threads/processes?

Comment: *unmap it from all the threads/processes?* - no way

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531.aspx): "*If `CreateFileMapping` is called to create a file mapping object for `hFile`, `UnmapViewOfFile` must be called first to unmap all views **and call `CloseHandle` to close the file mapping object** before you can call `SetEndOfFile`.*"

Comment: ok. Is there any way to know if its still mapped in another process?

Comment: The link does not suggest that this is a "known problem", but merely that  this is a system resource that is not automatically thread/process-safe, and each thread/process must 1) clean up after itself, and 2) synchronize with other threads.  Very typical in its basics, but also unfortunately very broad.

Comment: Um, the fact that you get `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE` means that *someone* has the file mapped. If it is not your app, then obviously it has to be some other app.

Comment: no any way. assume you work with map view of file. read/write to it view (memory). and suddenly somebody external unmap file, make view incorrect. what will be with your app, which try read/write to already not valid memory ?

Comment: @RbMm: It is *possible* to close a mapping in another process (`DuplicateHandle()` w/ `DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE`, for instance).  It is just not *advisable* to rip away someone else's mapping, like you said.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - file view not a handle. it can not be closed via duplicate handle. it can be unmapped external via [`ZwUnmapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwunmapviewofsection) - if we know process and section base address. and ready crash remote process

Comment: @RbMm: I didn't say it was possible to close a remote *view* of a mapping object, I said it was possible to close a remote mapping object itself. Two different things.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - sorry. probably i bad understand you. exist section object (mapping from win32 terminology) and it view. i understand mapping as view (usually use section word for object with handle). we need destroy section - so close it handles, if exist, and unmap all it views (if exist), because view is reference to section.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: It sounds like the threads are all under the OP’s control, so they probably just need some coordination, maybe a ref counting system so that only the last thread to unmap the file tries to call SetEndOfFile.